# Does current balance belong in a fact or a dimension table?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm starting out building a data warehouse and I'm struggling to get it straight in my head whether a balance amount is a fact or a dimension.

I have a 'Customer' table, which I believe should be a dimension.  It has attributes such as the customer's name.

It seems to make sense to me to create a fact table called something like 'Customer Account' that contains information such as the account balance, and link  the 'Customer' dimension to that.

However, 'Customer' will be a conformed dimension, as pretty much every fact table will be linked to it.  And I know that one common way that people want to slice and dice their data is by current balance (e.g. Show me how many X where the customers balance is over £500 in arrears).  So that suggests that the balance should be stored in the dimension.  But that 'feels' wrong to me.

I guess that if anyone wants a report that is filtered or grouped by balance then they could drill-across to the 'Customer Account' fact table - but that doesn't seem very user-friendly.

Perhaps I need to create a 'Customer Account' fact table, **and** also add the balance to the 'Customer' dimension.

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question: use both.

- In the dimension, to allow filtering based on current balance; balance must be updated for every transaction or at least every day;
- As a snapshot fact table, using the semi-aditive measure balance, to allow time series analysis on account balances, for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.  Thinking aloud... If I take that approach then would I need to add a new row to the dimension every time the balance changed (to allow point-in-time reporting), or would I be better simply overwriting the balance each time and only allow point-in-time reporting via a drill-across to the fact table?  If I take the first approach I'm wondering if I gain any benefit from having the fact table at all.  If I take the second approach then a user has to have a completely different approach to produce a point-in-time report than a current report.

Comment: I don't recommend treating balances as a SCD II attribute because that will cause your customer dimension to have almost the same cardinality of the fact table. I'd just update to the last known balance everytime and not keep track of history. That's what the Account balances snapshot fact table is for, to provide time series data for balances.